# Need to know main DIV of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am trying to come up with a strategy to detect the main content DIV of a site. Main content  div means: The div which contains the header, body, and the footer of the site.

It's a very difficult and slow process to detect it.

For instance, on http://www.goo.ne.jp/, I would detect id="bodyWrapper" or "minWidthInbox" because these divs contain the main content on the site.

I have also tried many algorithms to do so. But bacause of weird structures of sites, and inconsistencies, it's not possible for all sites to run by a single algorithm.

Table layout is especially hard to detect. :-(

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: so you want the contents of a website in a div? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: slow to detect WHAT? Can't even make sense of what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry!! so funny question. pls dont downvote him more, let him edit the quesion.

Comment: @Lenny , I dont need content but I need div (id/name) of div which carries content.

Comment: Please explain why down votes?? and question is not that funny.If not understood please ask your doubts.

Comment: You can't detect that, and it would be different for every page as every page is designed different and therefore could/will have a different structure, what do you need as an end result? May be there's something else you could do

Comment: There isn't a single way to get the correct div for what you want because there's no standard site architecture. Are you trying to do something clientside or serverside?

Comment: @Lenny , i have specified same in my question , but as i know there are standard layouts used by industry.like 2 columunar and three colunar..I have already created parsing for one columnar.

Comment: @Walialu , yes indeed.Grammer is funny, and spellings tooooo.Beacuse my butt is on fire.and I really want this..

Comment: What do you want to do with the Id/name of the div once you have got it?

Comment: @Lenny I bet he is trying to screen scrape :D

Comment: @Walialu I would assume so, but there's no reliable way of doing that over multiple unspecific websites, unless your just getting the area between the body tags... so some tag that is there in every web page...

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at Readability http://www.readability.com/. They have developed an algorithm to extract the content of a web page and remove all other elements, like header, footer, ads.

Unfortunately their algorithm is not public anymore. They have an API here: http://www.readability.com/developers/api.

There are also several implementations of their original algorithm out there. I have used on library for Python and one for NodeJS (https://github.com/arrix/node-readability) and they work pretty well.

Regarding your question about the main div, unless you are scrapping a specific website I wouldn't recommend searching for such a particular piece of code. I seems to me like you are after the content, and of course the html code of a website can contain pretty much everything, not just a main div.

Comment: Cool thanx man.vote up..Atleast you didnt down vote unlike others.I had high hopes from this group , but not now.People get upvotes for asking "why we use i as a counter in loops" but valid question is discouraged..

Comment: alex , i am creating algo for similar pattered sites like 2 columnar.So that i can parse atleast 50% sites correctly.

Comment: Hi Johnny, welcome to Stack Overflow! While I did vote up on the question, please don't beg others to upvote your post. Instead, take your time and write as clear as you can. Notice how the upvotes started to come in on your question *after* I edited your post and cleaned up the grammar? It is indeed an interesting question, it was just well hidden under a lot of hard to understand clutter. ;)  Good luck!